# Understanding multi-touch on android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm trying to track multi touch events on android (I need to track "touch down" and "touch up" for each finger). The problem is the PointerId does not seem to be consistent or somehow I'm having problems linking "down" events to "up" ones and as a result I'm missing some "up" events.

Here is the code I use to process MotionEvents:

```
int pointerIndex = me.getActionIndex();
int pointerId = me.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
final int action = me.getActionMasked();

switch (action)
{
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
{
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
    {
        System.out.println("ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId);
    }
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
{
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        System.out.println("Initial ACTION_DOWN Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId);
        pointerIndex = 0;
        pointerId = me.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId);
    }
    if (!idPressed[pointerId])
    {
        idGenerator++;
        idOffset[pointerId] = idGenerator;
        mView.DoTouchEvent(0, mePos[pointerId * 2] - location[0], mePos[pointerId * 2 + 1] - location[1], idOffset[pointerId]);
        idPressed[pointerId] = true;
        //System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId + " Gen: " + idOffset[pointerId]);
    }
    break;
}
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    {
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
        {
            System.out.println("ACTION_POINTER_UP Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId);
        }
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    {
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            System.out.println("Initial ACTION_UP Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId);
            pointerIndex = 0;
            pointerId = me.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            System.out.println("ACTION_UP Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId);
        }
        if (idPressed[pointerId])
        {
            mView.DoTouchEvent(1, me.getX(pointerIndex) - location[0], me.getY(pointerIndex) - location[1], idOffset[pointerId]);
            idPressed[pointerId] = false;
            //System.out.println("ACTION_UP Index: " + pointerIndex + ", ID: " + pointerId + " Gen: " + idOffset[pointerId]);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Here is the log recorded with the above code:

```
    08-24 12:13:32.603: I/System.out(3570): Initial ACTION_DOWN Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:32.603: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_DOWN Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:32.943: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:32.943: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.013: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_UP Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.013: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_UP Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.103: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.103: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.174: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_UP Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.174: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_UP Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.174: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_UP Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.214: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:33.214: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_POINTER_DOWN Index: 1, ID: 1
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): Initial ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): Initial ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): Initial ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): Initial ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): Initial ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
08-24 12:13:34.115: I/System.out(3570): ACTION_UP Index: 0, ID: 0
```

At the end of this log I had no finger on the screen, but as you can see there is no "up" event for ID: 1. (also I don't know why I get multiple events of the same type one after the other).

Am I missing something ? Anyone has any idea ?

Thanks,
/COsmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem to this and I'm posting here for others that may have the same problem, so: the problem was that I was not processing the MotionEvent right when it was receives, instead I was placing it in a queue and process everything on the next update loop. The problem was that I was actually holding a pointer to the MotionEvent and in some cases with fast/many touches, the content of those objects was replaced before the processing loop (most likely there is a pool of MotionEvent objects used by the system and so an object will be reused from time to time).